# Python regex search

Tags: python, regex

My previous example was not clear, I give another example  :

```
a = '123 - 48 <!-- 456 - 251 - --> 452 - 348'
```

And if i do something like :

```
[el for el in re.split(r' - ',a)]
```

I catch :

```
['123', '48 <!-- 456', '251', '--> 452', '348']
```

But I want this :

```
['123', '48 <!-- 456 - 251 - --> 452', '348']
```

Thanks...

Comment: you do(get that result...), with which python version? From my experience the el is of the type string in array comprehensions as opposed to using dict(....)

Comment: Ok@Update. Still, I consider non-capturing groups with `filter` one of the fastest solutions, especially for longer text. (Don't forget to pick an answer.)

Answer (score 5):

First remove the comments using something like this:

```
re.sub("<!--.*?-->", "", your_string)
```

then use your regex to extract numbers.

You can also use `?!...` (negative lookahead assertion) but that won't be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one regex you could use something like:

```
(\d+)(?!(?:[^<]+|<(?!!--))*-->)
```

As long as there are no "invalid" `-->`.

It matches numbers not followed by `-->`, without `<!--` in between.

Comment: it's incredibly slow (python 2.7) even for a strlen ~100. But it works

Comment: If it supports atomic groups or possessive quantifiers you could try `(\d+)(?!(?:[^<-]++|<(?!!--)|-(?!->))*+-->)`

Answer (score -1):

The result you posted is of `re.findall('(\d+)',a);`

```
re.findall('(?:\<\!--.+\d+.+--\>)|(\d+)',a)
```

['123', '48', '', '452', '348']

```
filter(None, re.findall('(?:\<\!--.+\d+.+--\>)|(\d+)',a))
```

['123', '48', '452', '348']

Comment: `1 -- 2 -- 3`, `1 <!--2--> 3`, couple of examples that would not work.